# Why is the equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-F_x}{F_y}$ true?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

My calc textbook says that if you have a function *F* such that *F*(*x*, *f*(*x*) = *y*) = $0$, then you can differentiate both sides of the equation with respect to *x* to receive the following:

$$\frac{dF}{dx}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

And, therefore, assuming $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\neq 0 $:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}}= -\frac{F_x}{F_y}$$

Here is my confusion. *F* would simply be a two-dimensional level surface. Since the value of *F* is constant (zero), wouldn't $F_y$ **necessarily** be $0$, as well as $F_x?$ After all, the rate of change of the height of a level surface in any direction should be $0$, right? This issue reminds me of an idea from calc $1$:

$$x = 0$$
$$ \frac{d}{dx}[x] = \frac{d}{dx}[0]$$
$$1 = 0$$

Of course, this assumption is false because it doesn't take into account that *x* is a constant. In this case, $\frac{d}{dx}[x] =0$. So why doesn't this also apply here with $F_x$ and $F_y$?

Comment: $F$ is a function, $F(x,y)=0$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^2,$ and it is usually a $1$-dimensional space in a two-dimensional space, if $F$ is continuous and not constant in any neighborhood. $F(x,f(x))=0$ states that the graph of $f,$ the points $(x,f(x))\in \mathbb R^2$ are a subspace of the first space